# How could I center a div that is inside a div? Auto margins aren't working

Tags: html, css

[Website where the issue exists](http://www.unisstudy.altervista.org)
When you login ( username: male / Password: male ), you see a sidebar at the right side. I've tried everything I can but i can't center the column of buttons on the right side. If you Inspect Element you can see that i set margin-left and margin-right to auto but it simply doesn't work. **How could I center the class "optionsWrapper" in class "options"?** Also how would i make class"options"'s height as long as the window? I have it at 100% right now but when i test it, its height is either too long or too short depending on the screen size that views the site.

Note: It looks somewhat okay on Chrome but on Firefox and Safari it looks abysmal and I have no idea why. Any help would really be appreciated!

HTML Setup:

```
      <div class='options'>
          <div class='optionsWrapper'>
              <div class='toggleButton' id='white'>
              </div>

              <div class='toggleButton'  id='yellow'>
              </div>

              <div class='toggleButton'  id='green'>
              </div>

              <div class='toggleButton'  id='red'>
              </div>

              <div class='toggleButton'  id='blue'>
                <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img class='settings_icon' src="Icons/Set 1/PNG/7.png"></a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

CSS Setup:

```
.options{
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #444444 url("http://nickbrombal.com/images/bg_pixel-grey.jpg") repeat fixed;
  padding-top: 1.2%;
}

.optionsWrapper {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
top: 50%;
position: absolute;
transform: translate(25%, -50%);
}

.toggleButton{
  width: 100%;
  height: 66px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Please share relevant code in the question, not just a link to the page you are working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only see half of a green button. (Testing in Firefox.)

Remove the `height` style from the `.options` rule, then remove the `position`, `top` and `transform` styles from the `.optionsWrapper` rule. Now the buttons show up at least.

The reason that the auto margins doesn't seem to work is that the buttons take up the whole width of the parent, so while the margins actually work, dividing up zero in two equal parts is still zero. If you specify a width for the buttons, for example `width: 65px`, you see that they are centered.

Comment: Your reply has been wonderful in solving my main issue of understanding why the auto margins don't work! Thank you so much for that! However, any ideas why it that specific part of the website looks so different across browsers?

Comment: @user3026860: I think that the reason for that is that you are using some styles that are contradictory (several different ways of positioning the same elements). Browsers are pretty good att following the standards, but the standards doesn't specify how invalid CSS should be interpreted, so that's where the browsers differ most.